# access variable from controller to custom directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs-directive

```
index.html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="webQueryApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestAppController">
       <div class="operationalArea"  my-Draggable  >  click me </div> 
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

 - 


style.css


.operationalArea {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}


app.js

var webQueryApp = angular.module("webQueryApp", [ ]);

        webQueryApp.directive('myDraggable', function(){
        return{
                //link start

                link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

      element.bind('click', function(event) {
     console.log("element clicked and arr is "+attrs.arr);

  });         
          }

                //link end
        };
        });

webQueryApp.controller('TestAppController', function($scope, $http) {
    var app = this;
    console.log("hello console");
    $scope.arr=[1,2,3,4];

});
```

you can see in plunker

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/aabS53ZgjKnrXWu1aFtt?p=preview
```

i want to use  controller arr value in custom directive.
    but it says undefined. while i am tring i can't have the scope of table.

other wise send me a reference where i can found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the plunker you provided, just modify the directive scope property to the follwing

```
scope: {
   data: '=',
}
```

and you are going to be able to use the array by calling `$scope.data`